# Количество разных чисел по модулю (оптимизация)

Tags: python

столкнулся вроде бы как с простой задачкой, но не получается уложиться в ограничение по памяти, заданное на сайте.

Задан отсортированный массив целых чисел. Найдите количество различных по модулю чисел среди элементов массива.

Входные данные:
Первая строка содержит количество чисел n (n ≤ 2 * 10^6). Вторая строка содержит n целых чисел, отсортированных по возрастанию. Массив может содержать одинаковые элементы.

Выходные данные:
Выведите количество различных по модулю чисел.

Пример :
Входные данные:

```
9
-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1
```

Выходные данные:

```
2
```

У меня два теста кушают 131 072 KiB, когда заданное ограничение - 128 MiB
Есть подозрения, что нужно всё сделать через словари, но я не совсем понимаю, как это оформить.
[Ссылка на задание](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/9007)
Вот мой код:

```
n = int(input())
lst_1 = [int(el) for el in input().split()]
counter = 0
lst = set(lst_1)
r = []
for i in lst:
    r.append(abs(i))
print(len(set(r)))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131400/discussion-on-question-by-nikita-sokolov------).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Задача оказалась про скорость ввода данных. Вот решение которое проходит все тесты ([результаты](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9835449)):

```
import sys


def read():
    READ_SIZE = 1024
    tail = ''
    while True:
        block = sys.stdin.read(READ_SIZE)
        if len(block) == 0:
            yield from tail.split()
            return
        text = tail + block

        last_ws = text.rfind(' ')
        if last_ws == -1:
            tail = text
            continue

        yield from text[:last_ws].split()
        tail = text[last_ws:]
    

input()
print(len(set(abs(int(w)) for w in read())))
```

Ограничения [задачи](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/9007) - одна секунда, 128MB. Я сделал несколько тестов, чтобы понять как эти ограничения работают.

Прочитаем данные самым привычным для Питона способом:

```
input()
print(len(input().split()))
```

[Результаты](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9834963). То что это решение не решает задачу не важно. Меня интересует только память и время. Тесты 9 и 10 исчерпывают память полностью. На что расходуется память? На строку, которую вернул `input()`. На миллион (буквально) маленьких строчек, которые нарезал `.split()` и на список хранящий эти строки.

Главный вывод: каким бы ни был алгоритм обработки этого списка в дальнейшем, мы не помещаемся в память. Так читать данные нельзя.

А как можно? Единственное решение высокого уровня, которое читает слова из строки без создания длинного списка - `re.finditer`. Если вы знаете другие, подскажите.

```
import re

input()
print(sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('[0123456789]+', input())))
```

[Результаты](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9835001). Снова нас не интересует правильность, только память и время. На этот раз по памяти мы проходит свободно. Наибольшее потребление на девятом тесте - 24MB. Память расходуется на входную строку и миллион (буквально) объектов которые описывают найденные подстроки. Эти объекты не должны хранится, полагаю что сборщик мусора не успевает их убирать. Не суть.

Время работы этого варинта обескураживает: `re.finditer` тратит 412ms на восьмой тест, `.split()` - 146ms. `re.finditer` в 2.8 раза хуже.

Времени, которое остаётся после чтения данных `re.finditer` не хватает чтобы посчитать правильный ответ:

```
import re

input()
print(len(set(int(m.group(0)) for m in re.finditer('[0123456789]+', input()))))
```

[Результаты](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9835844). Этот вариант даёт верные ответы, но не проходит по времени в тестах 9 и 10. Сколько времени нам не хватает? Восьмой тест в этом варианте - 840ms, в предыдущем - 412ms. Девятый тест в предыдущем - 758ms. Предполагая что обе программы имеют линейную сложность, получаем пропорцию для девятого теста на последнем коде: `758 / 412 * 840 = 1547ms`. На полсекунды больше лимита по времени.

Напишем ввод руками. Функция `read` читает входной поток небольшими кусками, не хранит его целиком, выдаёт наружу как можно быстрее. Проверим как быстро читаются данные таким образом:

```
import sys


def read():
    READ_SIZE = 1024
    tail = ''
    while True:
        block = sys.stdin.read(READ_SIZE)
        if len(block) == 0:
            yield from tail.split()
            return
        text = tail + block

        last_ws = text.rfind(' ')
        if last_ws == -1:
            tail = text
            continue

        yield from text[:last_ws].split()
        tail = text[last_ws:]
    

input()
print(sum(1 for _ in read()))
```

[Результаты](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9835412). Девятый тест занимает 374ms. Аналогичное время для `re.finditer` - 758ms. Рукописное чтение обогнало библиотечное в два раза - неожиданный результат.

Сравним времена `input().split()`, `re.finditer(..., input())` и `read()` на тестах которые прошли по памяти для всех трёх вариантах:

```
вариант                      тест 7   тест 8 

input().split()               125       146
read()                        185       193
re.finditer(..., input())     395       412
```

Самописный `read()` в полтора раза медленнее библиотечного `input().split()`, что подтверждает правило "чем выше уровень, тем быстрее код на Питоне". `re.finditer` разочаровал.

Для решения задачи пришлось идиоматичное но расточительное по памяти решение (`input().split()`) заменить менее быстрым но экономным рукописным (`read()`).

Comment: Получается, на питоне это никак не решить?

Comment: Я ещё пытаюсь. :(

Comment: Не пробовали (я бы сказал, идиоматический для мира Си подход), отсортировать (предполагаю, что для 10^6 даже в питоне это много быстрее секунды) и пройтись по двум массивам (с положительными и отрицательными числами)?

Comment: @avp, я последовал вашему совету: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1349227/416121. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

вот решение задачи за линейное время без множеств и прочего, что жрет и память и дополнительное время:

основные моменты:

1. мы идем слева направо по отрицательным числам (если и положительные - это значения не имеет)
2. мы идем справа налево по положительным числам
3. каждое уникальное левое число увеличивает счетчик уникальных чисел на 1
4. каждое уникальное правое число такое, что оно больше левого числа по модулю увеличивает счетчик на 1

код:

```
n = int(input())
data = list(map(int, input().split()))

count = 0

pos = 0
pos_r = len(data) - 1

while pos <= pos_r:
    # получить отрицательное число
    num = data[pos]
    count += 1

    # пропустить одинаковые отрицательные числа
    while pos <= pos_r and data[pos] == num:
        pos += 1

    # выйти, если все отрицательные числа перебраны
    if pos > pos_r:
        break

    # перебрать все положительные числа до модуля искомого отрицательного
    while data[pos_r] >= abs(num) and pos < pos_r:
        num_r = data[pos_r]

        if num_r > abs(num):
            count += 1

        # пропустить одинаковые положительные числа
        while pos_r >= pos and data[pos_r] == num_r:
            pos_r -= 1

print(count)
```

код для тестирования (с оптимизациями, которые дали 30-50% прирост скорости):

```
import time

limit = 10000000
data = [i for i in range(-limit, limit)]

start_time = time.perf_counter()

count = 0

pos = 0
pos_r = len(data) - 1

while pos <= pos_r:
    # получить отрицательное число
    num = data[pos]
    count += 1

    # пропустить одинаковые отрицательные числа
    pos += 1    # ОПТИМИЗАЦИЯ позволяет избежать входа в цикл, если числа находятся рядом
    while pos <= pos_r and data[pos] == num:
        pos += 1

    # выйти, если все отрицательные числа перебраны
    if pos > pos_r:
        break

    # перебрать все положительные числа до модуля искомого отрицательного
    num_abs = abs(num)  # ОПТИМИЗАЦИЯ, однократное вычисление абсолютного значения вне цикла, где оно используется
    while data[pos_r] >= num_abs and pos < pos_r:
        num_r = data[pos_r]

        if num_r > num_abs:
            count += 1

        # пропустить одинаковые положительные числа
        pos_r -= 1    # ОПТИМИЗАЦИЯ позволяет избежать входа в цикл, если числа находятся рядом
        while pos_r >= pos and data[pos_r] == num_r:
            pos_r -= 1

end_time = time.perf_counter ()

print(count)
print(end_time - start_time, "seconds")
print((2 * limit / (end_time - start_time)) * 4 / (1024 * 1024), "MB/sec")
```

Comment: по-моему, не будет работать на граничных случаях типа "один элемент" или "два разных элемента". Да и синтаксически есть проблемы с `map`

Comment: виноват, `map` подправил - я его у себя не использовал, а ставил тестовые выборки, проблема одна есть - ищу ошибку [-3, -2, -1]

Comment: все, скорректировал все `>=` теперь на всех своих выборках был правильный результат

Comment: Ваше решение укладывается в одну секунду?

Comment: скорость решения `O(n)`, скажите на каком объёме отсортированных данных надо проверить? Если что, то поиск одинаковых чисел (который у меня через while) можно сделать через простой бинарный поиск и еще увеличить скорость для последовательностей с большим кол-вом одинаковых чисел, правда для последовательности неповторяющихся числе скорость будет меньше, чем в текущей реализации, ну и в любом случае это будет быстрее, чем использовать множества

Comment: Сложность хорошая. Речь о константе. Ещё никто на Питоне не уложился в одну секунду и 128MB. https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/9007 .

Comment: ну тогда кто я такой, чтобы спорить с этим никем :) хотя конечно интересно было бы испытать алгоритм на данных. Проверил локально - 1секунда на 4МБ данных ( целые числа от -x до x)

Comment: чуть-чуть оптимизировал код - стало за 1секунду 6МБ данных ( целые числа от -x до x) и 26МБ (на одинаковых данных, т.е. в массиве только 1 уникальное число), так, еще чуть оптимизировал, поднял до 7,5МБ/сек

Comment: проверил максимальную скорость на своем компьютере - 12МБ/сек для последовательности уникальных данных (от -x до x) - там по сути 2 строчки кода всего, так что мои 7,5 - это 60+% от теоретически возможного ну и конечно еще универсальный код, потому что можно заложить анализ уникальных последовательностей и для них свои подалгоритмы вызывать (например, когда все числа в последовательности одинаковые)

Answer (score 0):

вот, попробовал сделать со словарем, но не знаю пройдет ли тест, попробуйте:

```
from re import finditer

s = '-33 -11 -3 -2 -1 -1 0 1 1 1 1 4 5 11 33'
d = {}

for m in finditer(r'\d+', s):
    d[m[0]] = d.get(m[0], 0) + 1

print(sum(v==1 for v in d.values()))  # 5
```

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9851208

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]